# Generating Compose Typography definitions

Tags: typography, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I am investigating android jetpack compose and would like to know the correct approach for defining typography resources. i have found a number of online examples such as [this](https://www.boltuix.com/2021/12/typography_27.html) one.

What I am unsure of is how each version of the font has been derived, e.g.

```
`displayLarge = TextStyle(
        fontFamily = jostFontFamily,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Light,
        fontSize = 57.sp,
        lineHeight = 64.sp,
        letterSpacing = 0.sp
    ),
`
```

how are the font size, line height and letter spacing calculated?

I assume these values will differ for each font family employed in an android application, however how are they arrived at? do you have to employ "trial and error" and see which values are acceptable? or is there an online website similar to Material Theme Builder that supports generation of the required values?

I have searched the web for free online resource similar to Material Theme Builder and failed to find anything suitable.

I have also tried downloading a number of fonts from https://fonts.google.com/ and employing the same values for font size, line height and letter spacing as shown above however I am not satisfied  with the final result.

the practice of manually setting the values for each variant of the font appears to be very tedious surely there is an approach where these values can be automatically generated.